# Matlab: ginput in GUI in a plot

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, coordinates, ginput

I am trying to get the coordinates from a plot that is inside a GUI, I wanted to use ginput function but I don't know how to use it in a plot inside a GUI. I have seen a framework called ginputax but I have not been able to make it work. My code is like this:

```
f=openfig('gui_final_work');
ctrl=guihandles(f);
[x y] = ginput(1);
```

I have also tried:

```
f=openfig('gui_final_work');
ctrl=guihandles(f);
[x y] = ginputax(1,ctrl.axes1);
```

but both cases generate a new figure separated from the GUI. Any hint will be appreciated...Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you make your GUI with GUIDE? In the docs for [openfig](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/openfig.html) they advise NOT to use that function to open GUIs created with GUIDE.

Comment: yes, I open GUIs created with GUIDE

Answer (score 2):

Try forcing the figure focus on your on newly opened figure:

```
f=openfig('gui_final_work');
figure(f)
[x y] = ginput(1);
```

Or try:

```
f=openfig('gui_final_work');
figure(gcf)
[x y] = ginput(1);
```

Comment: it does not work, after execute 
    [x y] = ginput(1);
a new figure is generated..